# link XML with java

Tags: java, xml, swing

i tried to make this code and link it with an xml file(UI to read data from xml file):

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private JComboBox<String> directorDropdown;
    private JButton searchButton;
    private JTextArea resultTextArea;

    public NewJFrame() {
        init();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                                      
private void init() {

        directorDropdown = new JComboBox<String>();
        directorDropdown.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {"Abdellah Ghayth", "Mouna Wacef", "ELaakad"}));
        getContentPane().add(directorDropdown);

        searchButton = new JButton("Search");
        searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    // Get the selected director from the dropdown
                    String nomRealisateur = directorDropdown.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    // Create a parser for the XML document
                    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

                    // Load the XML document into a Document object
                    Document document = builder.parse(new File("Catalogue.xml"));

                    // Find the films directed by the selected director and display their titles
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    NodeList films = document.getElementsByTagName("film");
                    for (int i = 0; i < films.getLength(); i++) {
                        Element film = (Element) films.item(i);
                        Element realisateur = (Element) film.getElementsByTagName("realisateur").item(0);
                        if (realisateur.getAttribute("ref").equals(nomRealisateur)) {
                            String titre = film.getAttribute("titre");
                            result.append(titre + "\n");
                        }
                    }
                    resultTextArea.setText(result.toString());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(searchButton);

        resultTextArea = new JTextArea();
        resultTextArea.setEditable(false);
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(resultTextArea));

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
                 try {
                // Spécifier le nom du réalisateur recherché
                String nomRealisateur = "ELaakad";

                // Créer un parseur de document XML
                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

                // Charger le document XML dans un objet Document
                Document document = builder.parse(new File("Catalogue.xml"));

                // Obtenir une liste des éléments "film" dans le document
                NodeList films = document.getElementsByTagName("film");

                // Créer un modèle de liste pour les titres de films
                DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();

                // Parcourir chaque élément "film" pour trouver ceux réalisés par le réalisateur spécifié
                for (int i = 0; i < films.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element film = (Element) films.item(i);
                    Element realisateur = (Element) film.getElementsByTagName("realisateur").item(0);

                    // Vérifier si le réalisateur correspond à celui recherché
                    if (realisateur.getAttribute("ref").equals(nomRealisateur)) {
                        String titre = film.getAttribute("titre");
                        listModel.addElement(titre);
                    }
                }

                // Créer une liste pour afficher les titres de films
                JList<String> list = new JList<String>(listModel);

 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

but it shows those errors:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: "path" (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:86)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:189)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:653)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:150)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:861)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:825)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:247)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:342)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:206)
    at NewJFrame$3.run(NewJFrame.java:132)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:771)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:741)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

i wrote the full path but it didn't work, i also copied the xml file to the build folder but it didn't work
the code above is about a user interface using swing to read data from an xml file using DOM API .

Comment: Add `System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"))` to somewhere in your code, this will tell you the "working directory", this the location that your program is looking for the (relative) file, try placing it there.  IF you need the file to be always be available at runtime (ie, it's not likely to change) you could add it as an embedded resource instead, and avoid this kind of mess (but it does make the file read only)

Comment: I also would avoid loading the file twice, building a DOM is expensive, so I keep the initial reference (to the DOM) and re-use it instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer that helped a lot thanks ! but now there is no result and no error

Comment: So now you need to start debugging your code - start with some `System.out` statements

Comment: @MadProgrammer when i tried to validate xml file it shows `cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'catalogue'. [2] `
and i'm sure the file is well formed

Comment: xml
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalogue>
 <personne identificateur="p1" nom="Abdellah Ghayth" age="45"/>
 <personne identificateur="p2" nom="Mouna Wacef" age="30"/>
 <personne identificateur="p3" nom="ELaakad" age="60"/>
  <film langue="Ar" titre="errisala" film-affiche="errisala.jpg">
   <realisateur ref="p3" />
    <acteur ref="p1" nomActeur="Hamza"/>
    <acteur ref="p5" nomActeur="Hind"/>
    <scenario>
      .... Le Message qui raconte L'histoire de l'islam ,
      l'acteur <refPerson ref="p1" /> a un rôle important..
   </scenario>
 </film>
</catalogue>```

Comment: I pasted the XML into a XML validator and it didn't seem to have any issues

Comment: @MadProgrammer yeah i'm sure there is no issue in the xml file but there is an error when i validate

Comment: I did a small amount of sanity testing and it works fine for me (I can traverse the `NodeList` and see the `realisateur` attribute value

Comment: @MadProgrammer what you think the problem could be ?

Comment: At a guess, a file encoding issue or "hidden" character (see encoding issue)